# ¿Como puedo hacer un programa en java que escoja palabras random?

Tags: java

Hola buenas saludos quisiera preguntarles una cosa
me mandaron hacer un programa que recoja de manera aleatoria una opción de la maquina y una opción del usuario
estaba haciéndolo con `import java.util.Random;`
pero me di cuenta que esto es solo aplicable con números y cuando llego al momento de comparación que quiero comparar la ***palabra de la maquina = palabraMaquina = palabra usuario***  no puedo hacerlo ya
que no puedo comparar un `int` con un `string`

esto es lo que tengo

```
package juego;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class juego {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        Random ga = new Random(); 

menu ( sc,   ga);

    }

    static void ramdom ( Scanner sc, Random ga) {
        System.out.println("Escoje entre Piedra / Papel / Tijeras "); 
        String eleccion;
        eleccion = sc.nextLine();

        int numeroAleatorio = ga.nextInt(3);

        System.out.println(numeroAleatorio);

        int resultado;
        resultado = numeroAleatorio;

        switch (resultado) { 
        case 0: 
            System.out.println("Piedra");
            break;
        case 1: 
            System.out.println("Papel");
            break;
        case 2: 
            System.out.println("Tijeras");
            break;
        }
```

Si no me logro explicar bien básicamente en el momento de escoger un numero aleatorio quiero que sea una palabra

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esto lo preguntan todo el tiempo. No importa que devuelva numeros!!! tus palabras deben estar numeradas y seleccionas una de ellas y listo :)

Comment: Una solución que es casi inmediata a lo que programaste es poner las tres palabras en un vector y que el número aleatorio sea el índice de ese vector.

Comment: puedo empezarlo a hacer de 0 sin problema, lo que me gustaria tener es el codigo para selecionar un caracter random

Answer (score 1):

Echa un vistazo a esté código. ¡Saludos!

```
static void ramdom ( Scanner sc, Random ga) {
    // Creo un arreglo con las posibles opciones
    String[] opciones = new String[3];

    opciones[0] = "Piedra";
    opciones[1] = "Papel";
    opciones[2] = "Tijeras";
    // Creo un arreglo con las posibles opciones

    System.out.println("Escoje entre Piedra / Papel / Tijeras "); 
    String eleccion = sc.nextLine();

    int numeroAleatorio = ga.nextInt(3);

    /* El número generado servirá como índice */
    String opcion = opciones[numeroAleatorio];
    System.out.println(opcion); // acá mostrará Piedra Pepel o Tijeras según el número generado
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me ha servido bastante para ordenar el código y la idea que tenía
al final me quedó algo así:

```
package pruebas;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class prueba {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        menu(sc);
    }
    static void menu(Scanner sc) {
        int eleccion; 
        System.out.println("Opciones :"
                + "\nOperar = 1"
                + "\nSalir = 2");
        eleccion = sc.nextInt();
        switch(eleccion) {
        case 1:
            values(sc);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.print("AAdios..!!!");
            break;
        default: {
            System.err.print("Signo no reconocido");
            menu(sc);
        }
    }
    }
        static void values (Scanner sc) {
            int piedra = 0, papel = 1, tijeras = 2, x = 0;
            int maquina = (int) (Math.random()* 3 + 0);
            int numUsuario;
            int opcionUsuario;
            System.out.println("Escoje una opcion : \n0 Piedra"
                    + "\n1 Papel"
                    + "\n2 Tijeras");
            numUsuario = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();



            if(maquina == 0) {
                System.out.println("La maquina ha escogido Piedra");
            }else if (maquina == 1) {
                System.out.println("La maquina ha escogido Papel");

            }else if (maquina == 2) {
                System.out.println("La maquina ha escogido Tijeras");

            }

            if(numUsuario == piedra) {
                System.out.println("Tu Has escogido Piedra");
                if (maquina == piedra) {
                    System.out.println("Empate");
                }else if (maquina == papel){
                    System.out.println("Pierdes");
                }else if(maquina == tijeras) {
                    System.out.println("Ganas");
                }
            }else if(numUsuario == papel) {
                System.out.println("Has escogido Papel");

                if (maquina == piedra) {
                    System.out.println("Ganas");
                }else if (maquina == papel){
                    System.out.println("Empate");
                }else if(maquina == tijeras) {
                    System.out.println("Pierdes");
                }
            }else  if (numUsuario == tijeras) {
                System.out.println("Has escogido Tijeras");

                if (maquina == piedra) {
                    System.out.println("Pierdes");
                }else if (maquina == papel){
                    System.out.println("Ganas");
                }else if(maquina == tijeras) {
                    System.out.println("Empate");
                }

        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo un ejemplo simple usando un array de nombres tomados, en este caso de un enum, aunque podrian provenir de un fichero, base de datos, etc. Creando un numero aleatorio comprendido en el valor de indice del array, se toma ese indice para mostrar el nombre correspondiente.

```
import  java.util.*;

public class NombreAleatorio{

    public static void main (String...args)
    {
        Nombres[] nombres = Nombres.values();

        int r = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * nombres.length);

        System.out.println(nombres[r]);

    }

   enum Nombres
   {
       ALBERTO,
       ALEJANDRO,
       CARLOS,
       DANIEL
   }

}
```

De esta forma te sera muy sencillo comparar nombres (String) con numeros (int). Puede realizarse de la siguiente forma:

```
"ALBERTO".equals(nombres[r].toString())
```

Saludos.

Comment: Mejor compareToIgnoreCAse